# Strange theme after downloading CairoDock

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, icons, cairo-dock

I downloaded CairoDock yesterday and since I rebooted my system it shows me this weird theme, with orange windows and little white borders around programs. Also my icons are messed up, the top right is showing some very old-fashioned icons instead of the normal humanity icons.

I tried to change the theme using Ubuntu Tweak Tool and MyUnity, but this did not have any effect. I am able to change the icons, but not the theme. I tried deleting CairoDock, but this did not have any effect. What else can I try?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you take a screenshot and put it here ?

Comment: By "Ubuntu Tweak Tool" do you mean Ubuntu Tweak or Unity Tweak Tool or something else? I don't think there's currently a utility called "Ubuntu Tweak Tool."

Comment: if you do as @OnlyMAJ suggest, you can use http://imgur.com - how did you 'download' CairoDock, or rather, how did you install it?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot to: http://imgur.com/bvvpB2T, i used Unity Tweak tool indeed instead of Ubuntu Tweak Tool, and i installed CairoDock using the repository command line commands.

Comment: Seems that you need to restart the window manager.

Comment: Errr... [these commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CairoDock#From_the_Repository.2BAC8-PPA_.28Stable.29)? First, Reinstall it and Reboot, and if that does not work, use `sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock` to remove it. Did it remove anything during the installation? Look in Software Centre, under the History tab.

Comment: Restarting the window manager gets stuck in "checking battery state" i am running an update on all my packages now, it does not seem that anything was removed during the installation of CairoDock.